# How to implement such situation in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have two functions A and B which should be running parallel.If `a` happens in `A` it should set variable `eventa`. If `b` happens in `B` it should set `eventb`. I'm checking `eventa or eventb` in a while loop and it's important to me to do something as `eventa or eventb` is set, and this checking function should be a thread ,too, running at same time as A and B.
I thought I should write A and B as threads to have them running parallel and define two global variable `eventa` and `eventb` and put a lock on both of them.Am I wrong? Is it the solution of this problem? 
Here is the algorithm of what I think I should do:

```
  thread A{
    while(1)
    {
    if(a){
      lock eventa;
      set eventa;
      unlock eventb;
         }
    }
   }


thread B{
while(1)
{

if(b){
  lock eventb;
  set eventb;
  unlock eventb;
     }
}

thread check {
while(1)
 {
if(eventa or eventb)
  { if(eventa)
      { lock eventa;
        unset eventa;
      } else if(eventb)
      { lock eventb;
        unset eventb;
      }
     call foo;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Wait on the events, or pass messages

Comment: Do you really want it to be multi-platform, or do you target a specific OS?

Comment: I would suggest some simple solution:

make static function that receives lets say int
from eventB pass 1 from eventA pass 0 , and have it done .
should make the job , if all the problem is in it.

Comment: @ manuell:I want it work in Linux, now I'm working on Fedora18 if it matters

Comment: @user2533527 @ David Heffernan:you mean thread A and B pass messages to thread check?And all of them should be still threads.yes?

Comment: Yes , it is trivial solution , I would do so or I would make threads to write it Data to shared queue and then check the queue in worker thread in while or in main it doesn't matter ;)